# Grabbing a dictionary given just a few keys and values

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, types

Suppose I have a list of dictionaries, all of which have the same keys. An instance of such a dictionary in the list might look like:

```
dict = {"Height": 6.0, "Weight": 201.5, "Name": "John", "Status": "Married"}
```

Given only a few (key, value) pairs, I want to extract all dictionaries satisfying those pairs. For example, if I have

```
attributes = {"Height": 5.5, "Name": "John"}
```

I want to extract all dictionaries whose height value is greater than or equal to 5.5 AND whose name value is John.

I'm able to write the code that can satisfy one OR the other, but dealing with mixed types (float and string) is throwing me off, so my AND operator is being confused I guess. The problem part of my code, for example, is:

```
for option in attributes.keys():
    if dict[option] == attributes[option] and dict[option] >= attributes[option]
    print dict
```

Comment: This isn't a very well specified problem.  How is the code supposed to know that the Height key, for example, is a minimum value - rather than an exact value to search for, like the Name key?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple different condition you have to do all of them, but instead of using `and` you can use `all` built-in function and a function for filtering the dictionaries, then use it within a list comprehension or `filter` function in order to get the expected dictionaries.

```
from operator import itemgetter

option1, option2, option3 = itemgetter(key1, key2, key3)(attributes)

def filter_func(temp_dict):
    # key1, key2, key3 have been defined already (keys in attributes)
    val1, val2, val3 = itemgetter(key1, key2, key3)(temp_dict)
    return all(option1 == val1, option2 => val2, option3 => val3)

filtered_result = filter(filter_func, list_of_dictionaries)
```

Also note that if it's possible that the dictionaries with your list don't have all the specified keys, the `itemgetter` might raise an `KeyError` for getting ride of that you can use `dict.get` attribute by passing a default value to it (based on your need).

For example for `val3` you can use `temp_dict.get(key3, 0)`.